# Adjusting axis ranges in Amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I would like to make bubble chart like the following using amcharts and I have come across a bubble chart example in amcharts (1). I would like to get some help/guidance on how to make axis range like the sample which I have given below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/**
 * Plugin: Arrange data pints into separate value "bands"
 * Relies on `bandValueScope` being there in the chart config
 */
AmCharts.addInitHandler( function( chart ) {

  // check if bandValueScope is set 
  if ( chart.bandValueScope === undefined )
    return;

  // iterate through data points and apply step value
  for ( var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++ ) {
    var add = chart.bandValueScope * i;
    for ( var x = 0; x < chart.graphs.length; x++ ) {
      chart.dataProvider[ i ][ chart.graphs[ x ].yField ] += add;
    }
  }

  // set up Y axis labelFunction to recalculate those values as well
  for ( var i = 0; i < chart.valueAxes.length; i++ ) {
    var axis = chart.valueAxes[ i ];
    if ( axis.applyBandValues ) {

      // set up labelFunction to recalculate labels
      axis.labelFunction = function( value, a, b ) {
        var newValue = value - Math.floor( value / chart.bandValueScope ) * chart.bandValueScope;
        if ( newValue === 0 )
          return "";
        newValue = newValue.toString();
        if ( axis.unit )
          newValue += axis.unit;
        return newValue;
      }

      // go through guides and recalculate their values as well
      if ( axis.guides && axis.guides.length ) {
        for ( var x = 0; x < axis.guides.length; x++ ) {
          var add = chart.bandValueScope * x;
          var guide = axis.guides[ x ];
          if ( guide.value !== undefined )
            guide.value += add;
          if ( guide.toValue !== undefined )
            guide.toValue += add;
        }
      }
    }
  }



}, [ "xy" ] );

/**
 * Create chart
 */
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 70,
  "balloon": {
    "fixedPosition": true,
  },

  /**
   * `bandValueScope` is a custom paramater which will be used by a plugin
   * to restructure data so that each data point is recalculated into a new 
   * band
   */
  "bandValueScope": 50,
  "dataProvider": [ {
    // North America

    // Home
    "x1": 35,
    "y1": 30,
    "v1": 35,

    // Health
    "x2": 31,
    "y2": 26,
    "v2": 35,

    // Life
    "x3": 21,
    "y3": 32,
    "v3": 20,

    // Long term
    "x4": 23,
    "y4": 35,
    "v4": 29,

    // Auto
    "x5": 11,
    "y5": 33,
    "v5": 25,

    // Theft
    "x6": 10,
    "y6": 38,
    "v6": 15
  }, {
    // Asia

    // Home
    "x1": 50,
    "y1": 28,
    "v1": 20,

    // Health
    "x2": 55,
    "y2": 25,
    "v2": 20,

    // Life
    "x3": 38,
    "y3": 28,
    "v3": 20,

    // Long term
    "x4": 42,
    "y4": 32,
    "v4": 20,

    // Auto
    "x5": 25,
    "y5": 31,
    "v5": 20,

    // Theft
    "x6": 20,
    "y6": 39,
    "v6": 20
  }, {
    // Europe

    // Home
    "x1": 90,
    "y1": 18,
    "v1": 100,

    // Health
    "x2": 85,
    "y2": 14,
    "v2": 85,

    // Life
    "x3": 70,
    "y3": 29,
    "v3": 50,

    // Long term
    "x4": 80,
    "y4": 22,
    "v4": 40,

    // Auto
    "x5": 50,
    "y5": 25,
    "v5": 40,

    // Theft
    "x6": 40,
    "y6": 35,
    "v6": 20
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "title": "Number of Policies Issued",
    "titleColor": "#ff7f27",
    "titleFontSize": 18,
  }, {
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "minimum": 0,
    "minVerticalGap": 20,
    "unit": "%",
    "title": "Avg. Normalized Premiums",
    "titleFontSize": 18,
    "applyBandValues": true,
    "guides": [ {
      "value": 0,
      "toValue": 50,
      "lineColor": "#e2e2e2",
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillColor": "#00c",
      "fillAlpha": 0.1,
      "label": "North\nAmerica",
      "boldLabel": true,
      "color": "#ff7f27",
      "position": "right"
    }, {
      "value": 0,
      "toValue": 50,
      "lineColor": "#e2e2e2",
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillColor": "#c00",
      "fillAlpha": 0.1,
      "label": "Asia",
      "boldLabel": true,
      "color": "#ff7f27",
      "position": "right"
    }, {
      "value": 0,
      "toValue": 50,
      "lineColor": "#e2e2e2",
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "fillColor": "#0c0",
      "fillAlpha": 0.1,
      "label": "Europe",
      "boldLabel": true,
      "color": "#ff7f27",
      "position": "right"
    } ]
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1.5,
  "sequencedAnimation": false,
  "legend": {
    "position": "right",
    "markerType": "circle"
  },
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: [[value]]",
    "title": "Home",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "valueField": "v1",
    "xField": "x1",
    "yField": "y1",
    "minBulletSize": 15,
    "maxBulletSize": 60,
    "lineColor": "#a6cf28"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: [[value]]",
    "title": "Health",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "valueField": "v2",
    "xField": "x2",
    "yField": "y2",
    "minBulletSize": 15,
    "maxBulletSize": 60,
    "lineColor": "#7fadd1"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[title]]: [[value]]",
    "title": "Life",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "valueField": "v3",
    "xField": "x3",
    "yField": "y3",
    "minBulletSize": 15,
    "maxBulletSize": 60,
    "lineColor": "#f9c900"
  }, {
    "title": "Long term",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "valueField": "v4",
    "xField": "x4",
    "yField": "y4",
    "minBulletSize": 15,
    "maxBulletSize": 60,
    "lineColor": "#ff8a00"
  }, {
    "title": "Auto",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "valueField": "v5",
    "xField": "x5",
    "yField": "y5",
    "minBulletSize": 15,
    "maxBulletSize": 60,
    "lineColor": "#ff1568"
  }, {
    "title": "Theft",
    "bullet": "circle",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "bulletAlpha": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "valueField": "v6",
    "xField": "x6",
    "yField": "y6",
    "minBulletSize": 15,
    "maxBulletSize": 60,
    "lineColor": "#689494"
  } ]
} );
```

[image: Bubble Chart]

(1.) https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/05584b0b6afd661337b3ce5c8d6a14e3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `offset` both value axes of your bubble chart to center them. However, the `offset` values are defined in pixels, so unfortunately the axes will not keep their position when the chart is zoomed or panned. So you'll probably have to disable these features in this case.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  // ...
  "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "bottom",
    "offset": -200,
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 100
  }, {
    "position": "left",
    "offset": -200,
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 100
  }]
});
```

Here's a Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/137ecc09f89b5303b66944e4cf278b14?editors=0010.

You could also use `minimum` and `maximum` values for both value axes to make it easier to center your axes.

ValueAxis offset: https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#offset

Comment: I would like to have equal ranges for x-axis and y-axis. Also would like to add titles for each quadrants. May be for example [like this](https://pasteboard.co/Ha3FqDC.png). Is that possible?

Comment: For that, you can use `allLabels`: https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Label